# Calculate when jobs scheduled with different frequencies will align

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, modules

Suppose I have the following "tasks" scheduled to "run" at the following frequecies:

$t_1$ --> Every $3$ hours, on minute $0$

$t_2$ --> Every $5$ hours, on minute $0$

$t_3$ --> Every $2$ hours, on minute $0$

$t_4$ --> Every $5$ minutes

How can I calculate when these tasks will run at the same time?

For instance, how can I calculate:

1. How long it takes for $t_1$ and $t_2$ to run on the same minute?
2. How long does it take for $t_1$, $t_3$, $t_4$ to run on the same minute?
3. How long does it take for all of them to run on the same minute?

**My approach**

For the first comparison, I would think that by looking when 
$$3 \times n_\text{periods} \mod 12$$
 equals 
$$5 \times n_\text{periods} \mod 12$$

Is this the correct path? And how would I find a formula that tells me how much I need to wait for them to align?

My idea is that I would have $$180\times n \equiv 300\times n \equiv 120 \times n \equiv 5 \times n \qquad \mod 12$$

which I think is equivalent to

$$0\times n \equiv 0\times n \equiv 0 \times n \equiv 5 \times n \qquad \mod 12$$

Comment: notice that you do nod need to bother about the task that runs every 5 minutes, it will always align with the other three.

Comment: Take the least common multiple of the periods.

Comment: Let $x$ denote the number of times $t_1$ happen and $y$ denote the number of times $t_2$ happen. $3x -5y = 0$.....
(1, 1) = -2,
(2, 1) = 1,
(3, 2) = -1,
(4, 2) = 2,
(5, 3) = 0 AHA
If $3(5) - 5(3) = 0$ then $3(5n) -5(3n) = 0$ is also true, where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Any integer multiple of $3$ AND $5$ causes the tasks to run together. Numbers which are multiples of $3$ and $5$ are also multiples of $15$. This means the multiples of $lcm(3, 5)$ are all the times after which the tasks $t1$ and $t2$ would run at the same time.

Hence after every $15n$ hours, the tasks would run together.